# How can I create a dotnetnuke user account properly from the command line?

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

I am trying to create a command line quick program to do a once-off import of users from an old system (non-DNN) to a new system.  However, a `NullReferenceException` gets thrown at the following line of code:

```
        var user = new UserInfo();
        user.PortalID = portalId;
        user.FirstName = firstName;
```

On that last line is where the exception occurs.  I know this code works when run in a module, as it's part of a library I'm using.  I imagine that this is erroring because the `UserInfo` class is relying on information that's usually setup in a web environment.

Is there any way I can do this?  I really don't want to have this as a module running on a production site.

Comment: Are you sure that it's `user.FirstName = firstName;` that throws the exception and not the line above?  If so, then it's `firstName` that's null, not your `UserInfo` object.

Comment: That's what visual studio is showing, and firstname is not null.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the necessary providers in order to use the `UserController` and `UserInfo` classes. The most straightforward way to do this is to use the website's working configuration and implement the app as a DNN module. 
But you can also try to copy the required DLL's and configuration sections from the DNN site to the console application, and use the DNN source to debug problems.

In this case, the source tells that setting the `UserInfo` object's `FirstName` property fails because the `FirstName` property is backed by the profile provider, which uses the caching provider and data provider for data access.
By default, profile is implemented by the `DNNProfileProvider` that uses the `FileBasedCachingProvider` and `SqlDataProvider` to get the profile properties and data. Profile property definitions are retrieved also for a new `UserInfo` object when `ProfileController.GetUserProfile` is called. That is why the `NullReferenceException` gets thrown.

The corresponding properties in DNN 5.6.3 are:

**UserInfo.vb**

```
<SortOrder(1), MaxLength(50), Required(True)> _
Public Property FirstName() As String
    Get
        Return Profile.FirstName
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As String)
        Profile.FirstName = Value
    End Set
End Property

<Browsable(False)> _
Public Property Profile() As UserProfile
    Get
        'implemented progressive hydration
        'this object will be hydrated on demand
        If _Profile Is Nothing Then
            _Profile = New UserProfile
            ProfileController.GetUserProfile(Me)
        End If
        Return _Profile
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As UserProfile)
        _Profile = Value
    End Set
End Property
```